# Print the path in the maze

Tags: java, indexing, printing, maze

I'm trying to print the path of the maze. It's labeled with "*".

With System.out.println(maze[a.row][a.col]);

It will return me back the "* " since I set it to star.

How can I print the actual location of the star?

```
 public void resolve()  {
        Set<Cell> set = new HashSet<Cell>();
        set.add(new Cell(5,9,null));
        while(true){
            Set<Cell> set1 = new HashSet<Cell>();
            Cell a = colorCell(set, set1);

            if(a!=null) {
                while(a!=null)  {
                    maze[a.row][a.col] = '*';
                   // System.out.println(maze[a.row][a.col]);
                    a =a.from;
                }
                break;
            }

            if(set1.isEmpty())  {
                operations++;
                System.out.println("NOT FOUND!");
                break;
            }
            set = set1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: well, 'a.row' is one number of the coordinate, 'a.col' is the other.

Comment: Oh yea, how I miss that. Got it working now.